# bash script: change all & to &amp; in all files

Tags: bash

I have a folder with a lot of XML Files.
A bunch of them have `&` in it which should be converted to `&amp;`.

I'm not a bash guru but can I somehow change all this chars in all files with a bash script ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to pass the file through a `sed` filter, as in the following transcript:

```
$ echo '
this is line 1
this is line 2 with a & character.
and this is line 3 with & and & on it' | sed 's/&/&amp;/g'

this is line 1
this is line 2 with a &amp; character.
and this is line 3 with &amp; and &amp; on it
```

To do this with a group of files, you can use the in-place (with backup naturally) variant:

```
sed -i.bak 's/&/&amp;/g' *.xml
```

Comment: this will screw up all the other named entities though. For example, &lt; will become &amp;lt;

Comment: @Kim, yes it will. Probably the quickest way to fix that would be to pass the resulting file through a series of reversal operations like: `s/&amp;lt;/&lt;/g`.

Answer (score 3):

sed can do in-place replacement for you on all the files in the current working directory,

```
sed -i 's/&/&amp;/g' *
```

If you want it to go multilevels, something like

```
for file in `find`; do sed -i 's/&/&amp;/g' $file; done
```

If you only want to do replacement on files with .xml extension, which might be useful, do

```
for file in `find -iname '*.xml'`; do sed -i 's/&/&amp;/g' $file; done
```

Answer (score 2):

```
!/bin/bash
startdirectory="/home/jack/tmp/tmp2"
searchterm="&"
replaceterm="&amp;"
        for file in $(grep -l -R $searchterm $startdirectory)
          do
           sed -e "s/$searchterm/$replaceterm/ig" $file > /tmp/tempfile.tmp
           mv /tmp/tempfile.tmp $file
           echo "Modified: " $file
        done
echo "Done!"
```